# Ajax Crud Returning Error Message

Tags: php, ajax

I have an ajax crud table. It works perfectly fine when i want to edit and view (modal pops-up with correct info). Now when i submit the modal to insert a new user i get an error from php and ajax saying there is not data available but when i run var_dump in php it shows they are values. i have an isset condition to check if values are posted, if they are it should assign the posted data to a php variable else if false it will pass the error back to ajax.

The issue is no matter what i do it always returns the condition as false despite the data being posted

PHP Code

```
<?php    
var_dump($_POST);
$balance = $nextdate  = $error = $action = $interest_id = "";
$valid = true;
if(isset($_POST['balance']) && empty($_POST['balance']))
{
    $balance = ['balance'];
}
else
{
    $valid = false;
    $error .= "* balance is required.\n";
    $balance = '';

}

if(isset($_POST['nextdate']) && empty($_POST['nextdate']))
{
    $nextdate =$_POST['nextdate'];
}
else
{
    $valid = false;
    $error .= "* date is required.\n";
    $accountnumber = '';
}


if(isset($_POST['interest_id']) && empty($_POST['interest_id']))
{
    $interest_id = $_POST['interest_id'];
}
else
{
  $valid = false;
  $error .= "* email is required.\n";
    $interest_id = "";
}

?>
```

Ajax Code

```
if(valid == true)
            {
                var form_data = {
                    balance : balance,
                    nextdate : nextdate,


                    action : action,
                    interest_id : interest_id
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url : "insert.php",
                    type : "POST",
                    data : form_data,
                    dataType : "json",
                    success: function(response){
                        if(response['valid']==false)
                        {
                            alert(response['msg']);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(action == 'add')
                            {
                                $("#add_new_user_modal").modal('hide');
                                html += "<tr class=user_"+response['interest_id']+">";
                                html += "<td>"+response['interest_id']+" </td>";
                                html += "<td>"+response['balance']+" </td>";
                                html += "<td>"+response['nextdate']+" </td>";


                                html += "<td><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='edit_user("+response['interest_id']+");'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='delete_user("+response['bank_id']+");'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i></a></td>";
                                html += "<tr>";
                                $("#usersdata").append(html);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                window.location.reload();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

These are my var_dump results

```
array(4) 
{ ["balance"]=> string(8) "50000.00" 
["nextdate"]=> string(10) "2016-08-18" 
["action"]=> string(4) "edit" 
["interest_id"]=> string(19) "anonymous@gmail.com" }
```

Comment: Why do you always test those post values for an empty value, just to use that empty value then? That makes no sense, sorry. You want to use `!empty(...)` instead, so the negation, since you only want to _skip_ the post value usage if the posted value is in fact empty. Your logic in that is borked.

Comment: Hi arkascha i have made the change but still returns false...the php file response shows this {"valid":false,"msg":"* balance is required.\n* date is required.\n* email is required.\n"}

Comment: Sounds strange. I suggest you add a dump of the `$_POST` super global variable to the question. Note: do _not_ add it here in a comment. There is an `edit` button below your question. _Use it._

Comment: so i ran the var_dump function before the isset if statements and it shows an array of the values posted. when i view it in the Network Tab on Developers Tools it shows those values but when i double click the php for further info it shows [ array(0){} {"valid":false,"msg":"* balance is required.\n* date is required.\n* email is required.\n"} ]

Comment: I specifically asked to _add_ the dump to the question.

Comment: Good god! Not the _dump statement_, the _value array_!

Comment: Sorry for testing your patience, i didnt understand what you meant

Comment: All fine. No Problem. I do not see that result with that data. Please clear or disable your browser cache and do a "deep reload".

Comment: I managed to disable the cache but nothing new ,i even used Cache Killer extension but still same result..i think i might have to rewrite my php script to bypass this

Comment: No, do not try to mske wild attemot. Instead Unterstand what is going on. Take your time, Step by stepyou will finally understand what is going on. And you will have learned something.

Comment: you right....thanks a million...willl tell you once i have solved it

Comment: One other thing to help is debugging. Is to use tools on the browser. I use firebug with firefox see what the browser is sending and receiving. This helps a lot with ajax.

Comment: The client side can only see a fraction of what is going on. You need to dive into the server side. Two strategies: dump all kind of stuff into the log files and monitor those live (tail command is your friend) or, more advanced, install xdebug, a real php debugger and use it with your IDE. Much more efficient, but non trivial to setup...

Answer (score 0):

Your test is incorrect. You accepting a blank value. Thats why fails when you have a value.

```
if(isset($_POST['balance']) && empty($_POST['balance']))
```

should be

```
if(isset($_POST['balance']) && !empty($_POST['balance']))
```

Comment: Hi jason, thanks for the response...i have made the changes but still it returns false.... When i check my response it shows this  "{"valid":false,"msg":"* balance is required.\n* date is required.\n* email is required.\n"} "

Answer (score -1):

So i finally figured it out, the problem was the '== 'add'' on the if statement

Original

```
if($action=='add')
```

Changed

```
if($action = 'add')
```

Comment: uhm... no... that is the same as `$action = 'add'; if (true) ...` surely that's not what you want....

Comment: `=` is an _assignment_ in php (and most other languages), `==` is a _comparison_.